# Mahalanobis distance to the ellipsoid center

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I am confused about the following description:

If we parameterize the ellipsoid $E$ as: $E = \{x|\ ||Ax-b||_2 \leq 1\}$. $A \in S_{++}^n$
Then the Mahalanobis distance to the ellipsoid center is $M(z,E) = ||Az-b||_2$.

How to explain this? How to show this is indeed the distance to the center explicitly?

Comment: I don't see how $x\|Ax-b\|_2 \leq 1$ would be an ellipsoid. Sure there is not a typo?

Comment: three lines too close

Comment: is the first line supposed to mean "such that"? Im used to seeing colon mean that.

Comment: As I see it there is nothing to show. It's pretty much the definition of Mahalanobis distance.

Comment: Hmm..$||Az-b||_2$ is like the distance from $b$ to $R(A)$., which is from the basic linear algebra. I am confused about why this is equal to the distance to the ellipsoid center? Although it is the definition, I hope for a intuitive understanding.

Comment: Mahalanobis distance is just a fancy name for a linearly skewed euclidean distance. That's all it is.